How to check the Variances between 2 estimators are same or not
Let say I have 2 batches of electric bulb from some manufacturing processes
First batch was run from 10 am to 2 pm (just assume). In this batch total $N_1$ number of bulbs are produced and among them $D_1$ are defective. So I calculate the unbiased estimate of probability of defective bulb as $\hat p_1 = \frac{D_1}{N_1}$
Second batch observed from 1 pm to 3pm on the same machine. Therefore, there are some overlap in terms of produced bulbs between first batch and second batch. Here, total $N_2$ number of bulbs are produced and among them $D_2$ are defective. So I calculate the unbiased estimate of probability of defective bulb as $\hat p_2 = \frac{D_2}{N_2}.$
I would like to have some idea if variances of the estimates $\hat p_1$ and $\hat p_2$ are actually different.
Given that I have information of all $N_1$ and $N_2$ bulbs i.e. which one are defective and which are not, how could I conclude if variances are same or not?
In this experiment, total number of produced bulbs i.e. $N_1$ and $N_2$ are known and fixed. However the actual probability of defective items may be slightly different because they are produced in different batches therefore subject to different in materials and other external factors.

I think you have assumed that the probability of defect is constant across time. Maybe that should be stated explicitly in the question. Also, what are random in your setting? Did you condition on $N_i$?

@ZackFisher Thanks for your response. I have updated my original post with these information

So, within a batch, is the probability of each item being defect constant or varying? Also, how are they dependent within a batch?

Probability of being defect change for different batch. The structure of dependence is unknown but any simple form can be assumed if that aids to find some solution of the original question. Actually, I am not looking some explicit solution, an intuitive solution will be helpful as well - if variances of these 2 estimates can be safely assumed to be same or not

@MartinModrák when you say variance is equal if and only if the mean is equal - can you please elaborate? What exactly is mean here?

I might have misunderstood the question - if are you indeed interested in the variance of the estimates (relative to hypothetical repetitions of the same experiment) and not the variance of the distribution of failure than my question doesn't apply.

@MartinModrák My question is on Variance of Estimates

Do you mean the variance of the estimators as theoretical mathematics, or do you want to know about the variances of your observed data? You seem to be asking about the former, but the latter would be a much more common question, a difference in variance between two groups.

@Dave as you said correctly, I meant variance of the estimators as theoretical mathematics
